# Android - xml ampersand conversion

Tags: java, android

I have a sax parser with an xml tag that contains the following text: "A & amp; B" (There's no space there - added so it will not convert to & here)

It's as though it's getting converted twice and escaping due to ampersand with a result of "A". Here's the process:

Xml file is downloaded

```
InputStream _inputStream = _urlConnection.getInputStream();
                        BufferedInputStream _bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(_inputStream);
                        ByteArrayBuffer _byteArrayBuffer = new ByteArrayBuffer(64);

                        int current = 0;
                        while((current = _bufferedInputStream.read()) != -1)
                        {
                            _byteArrayBuffer.append((byte)current);
                        }

                        FileOutputStream _fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(_file, MODE_PRIVATE);

                        _fileOutputStream.write(_byteArrayBuffer.toByteArray());
                        _fileOutputStream.close();
```

Data is converted with Sax in the endElement

```
else if (inLocalName.equalsIgnoreCase(_nodeTitle))
        {
            _titleValue = currentValue;
            currentValue = "";
        }
```

In debug, the ampersand is already converted and the data truncated when I read it in my characters method in the handler.

I've seen a lot of questions about this but never a solution. Any ideas?

Thanks

Parser:

```
List<PropertiesList> _theList = null;

        try 
        {
            // Create Factory, Parser, Reader, Handler
            SAXParserFactory _saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser _saxParser = _saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader _xmlReader = _saxParser.getXMLReader();
            HandlerReps _handler = new HandlerReps(inRegion, inAbbreviation);

            _xmlReader.setContentHandler(_handler);
            _xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(inStream));

            _theList = _handler.getTheList();
        }
```

Handler:

```
// Called when Tag Begins
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String inLocalName, String inQName, Attributes inAttributes) throws SAXException 
    {
        currentElement = false;
    }

    // Called when Tag Ends
    @Override
    public void endElement(String inUri, String inLocalName, String inQName) throws SAXException 
    {
        currentElement = false;

        // Title
        if (inLocalName.equalsIgnoreCase(_nodeValue))
        {
            if (_stateValue.equalsIgnoreCase(_abbreviation) && 
                _countryValue.equalsIgnoreCase(_region))
            {
                // Construct the object
                PropertiesRegion _regionObject = new PropertiesRegion(_titleValue, _address1Value);

                cList.add(_regionObject);

                Log.d(TAG, _regionObject.toString());
            }

            _titleValue = "";
            _address1Value = "";
        }

        // Title
        else if (inLocalName.equalsIgnoreCase(_nodeTitle))
        {
            _titleValue = currentValue;
            currentValue = "";
        }

        // Address1
        else if (inLocalName.equalsIgnoreCase(_nodeAddress1))
        {
            _address1Value = currentValue;
            currentValue = "";
        }
    }

    // Called to get Tag Characters
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] inChar, int inStart, int inLength) throws SAXException 
    {
        if (currentElement) 
        {
            currentValue = new String(inChar, inStart, inLength);
            currentElement = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show us more of the code that actually parses the XML. Downloading the stuff from URL to file is boring. :-) Unless you're doing something wrong in openFileOutput(). And besides, the download done in a rather inefficient way here, but that's a different question. In a nutshell: don't use the single-byte methods of InputStream/OutputStream.

Comment: I added the download code in case there's something related I am not aware of - as in &amp; is getting converted at that point. I've done the exact same process with a DOM parser but the performance was unacceptable. The output was correct though.

Comment: Still not really enough context, but I gave it a try anyway. See my answer below.

Comment: Not sure what else to give you - that's the complete parser and handler minus exceptions and initializing variables.

Comment: Well, we don't know what HandlerReps is, getTheList() etc. But anyway, see my answer below, fix your code accordingly, and you'll be fine.

Comment: HandlerReps is the handler shown - getTheList is just the getter (return). I should have clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very likely the cause of your problem:

```
    if (currentElement) 
    {
        currentValue = new String(inChar, inStart, inLength);
        currentElement = false;
    }
```

For each text content node, the SAX parser may send multiple characters() events to your handler. You only get the whole text if you concatenate all these events. But in your code, only the first of these events is used, because then you set `currentElement = false`.

The problem is not ampersand conversion. As a general rule, when you describe a problem, it is often better to only describe the symptoms, not any supposed causes.

Comment: OK - I got it. It's not the conversion. I thought '&amp;' versus a naked ampersand affects how Sax handles the output. It doesn't.

Comment: The text is (very likely) broken into multiple events _because of_ the `&amp;`. SAX is an extremely performance-minded API, that's why it is sending text as multiple events. The parser reads character arrays, and if it finds an `&amp;`, it sends everything up to the `&` to the handler, then sends a single unescaped `&` character, and then the rest of the array after `&amp;`. This way, the parser can avoid creating a new character array just to unescape the `&amp;`. (Note that this is one way a SAX parser may work, there are other possiblities.)

Comment: I follow you now. I had read that '&amp;' versus a naked ampersand affects how Sax handles/builds the character array. Obviously that's not true. In any event, made the changes you suggested and it works perfectly now. I appreciate the help!

Comment: If there was a 'naked ampersand' in your XML file the SAX parser would simply throw an exception. Stuff like "A & B" is not allowed anywhere in XML input.